# Update method - Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'entity') error 500

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I test my app by postman:

statuscode:500

messsage: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'entity')

details: at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Entry[TEntity](TEntity entity)\r\n   at API.Data.UserRepository.Update(AppUser user) in C:\Users\vu227\DatingApp\API\Data\UserRepository.cs:line 67\r\n   at API.Controllers.UsersController.UpdateUser(MemberUpdateDto memberUpdateDto) in C:\Users\vu227\DatingApp\API\Controllers\UsersController.cs:line 51\r\n   at lambda_method101(Closure , Object )\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   at API.Middleware.ExceptionMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) in C:\Users\vu227\DatingApp\API\Middleware\ExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 29"

AppUser

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using API.Extensions;

 namespace API.Entities
  {
   public class AppUser
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public  byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string KnownAs { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime LastActive { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string  Gender { get; set; }
    public string Introduction { get; set; }
    public string LookingFor { get; set; }
    public string Interests { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string  Country  { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}
```

}

```
public void Update(AppUser user)
    {
        _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

line 67 in UserRepostory is

```
_context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Controller Put method looks like:

```
   [HttpPut]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateUser(MemberUpdateDto memberUpdateDto)
    {
        var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;
        var username = claimsIdentity.Name;
        var user = await _userRepository.GetUserByUsernameAsync(username);

        _mapper.Map(memberUpdateDto, user);

        _userRepository.Update(user);

        if (await _userRepository.SaveAllAsync()) return NoContent();

        return BadRequest("Failed to update user");
    }
```

Line 51 is

_userRepository.Update(user);

MemberUpdateDto:

```
 namespace API.DTOs
  {
   public class MemberUpdateDto
    {
    public string Introduction { get; set; }
    public string LookingFor { get; set; }
    public string Interests { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    
     }
  }
```

Mapper:

```
 public class AutoMapperProfiles : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfiles()
    {
        CreateMap<AppUser, MemberDto>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.PhotoUrl, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => 
                src.Photos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsMain).Url))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Age, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DateOfBirth.CalculateAge()));;
        CreateMap<Photo, PhotoDto>();
        CreateMap<MemberUpdateDto, AppUser>();
    }
}
```

Comment: From the stack trace, it doesn't look like the exception is happening in `Update` method. can you please elaborate your issue. Where do you see that exception and the stack trace?

Comment: 500 error indicates an error occurred in the server while processing the request.  You can check the event logs in server to see if there is any error.  Your code is giving an exception because you did not handle the case where the response status is not 200 OK.

Comment: I am edited my question, 
I used ResrereMap() but it didn't work

Comment: There is any field which is not accepted null in `DB` check your DB table will get your answer.

Comment: Can you show me how to fix it?

Comment: Have your problem been solved ? If not  , have you try to set the breakpoint to see the value of user ?